# Actions on Google, how change audio volume while an Action streams MP3?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-home

My action streams audio to a Google-Home via MediaResponse webhook call. This works well, but even changing the volume isn't possible while streaming! 
Tested on simulator and Google-Home mini. Only intents of my action are recognized.

My expectation was, that the Google standard commands (volume up, down, ask the time...) are still working, even if a started action streams the audio.
But Google does not understand the command and cancels my action after 4 unrecognized tries.

Is this a normal behavior? Hopefully not, would be a big show stopper...

Comment: This is normal behavior, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users can now use voice commands to control the volume while your Action is using the Media Response.